# Create JSX elements based on prop value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a 4 dots indicative of user's [streak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31No7.png).

Full circles represent how big the streak is (2 full circles mean that streak==2). At start the streak equals 0. I've created a component to manage this and it works perfectly fine but I wonder whether there is a better way to do this. If I had 100 cases, the code would get incredibly messy. So is there a better way to do this that doesn't involve writing code for every single case?

```
const Streak = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Your streak</h2>
      <div className="streak-progress">
        {(() => {
          switch (props.streak) {
            case 0:
              return (
                <>
                  <i className="far fa-circle"></i>
                  <i className="far fa-circle"></i>
                  <i className="far fa-circle"></i>
                  <i className="far fa-circle"></i>
                </>
              );
            case 1:
              return (
                <>
                  <i className="fas fa-circle"></i>
                  <i className="far fa-circle"></i>
                  <i className="far fa-circle"></i>
                  <i className="far fa-circle"></i>
                </>
              );
            case 2:
              return (
                <>
                  <i className="fas fa-circle"></i>
                  <i className="fas fa-circle"></i>
                  <i className="far fa-circle"></i>
                  <i className="far fa-circle"></i>
                </>
              );
            // more cases
            default:
              return <h2>Error</h2>;
          }
        })()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Streak;
```

Comment: I didn't quite get the point of returning exact same thing within each `case`

Comment: Why not use a loop ?

Comment: I'm new to react and wasn't quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a simple loop:

```js
const streakJSX = (current, max) => {
  const components = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    components.push(<i className={`${i < current ? fas : far} fa-circle`}></i>);
  } 
  return components;
}
```

[Here is a working example (with ○ and ● instead of your icons just for simplicity)](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-framework-msylk?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

in your current situation u can use this component instead...:

```
  const Streak = (props) => {
  const dots = [true,true,true,true].map((bool,i)=>i > prop.streak);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Your streak</h2>
      <div className="streak-progress">
         {dots.map((bool,i)=>
            <i className={(bool?'far':'fas')+" fa-circle"}></i>
          )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Streak;
```